# Programmatically Setting Visible Attribute to False on a DIV Inside ASPX Page Markup Still Won't Hide It

Tags: html, asp.net, dom

I have the following code successfully adapting the DOM (I can see the results by clicking View Source in the browser)--yet the DIV content it's supposed to hide isn't being hidden. What will hide it?

```
Dim cmsClearwayNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='clearway']")
cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("runat", "server")
cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("visible", "false")
```

Here's the markup. Note the visible attribute on the outer DIV:

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper" id="clearway" runat="server" visible="false">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://testclearway.com/">
      <i class="fa fa-desktop custom-icon">
         <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
      </i>
      <span class="hidden-xs">Connect via Clearway</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best solution I've found for this issue after rummaging through several resources. I wouldn't consider it a workaround, but an actual solution. The problem we're trying to solve is hiding the DIV. Well, let's put an ASP panel around it, like pnlClear below:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlClear">
    <div class="icon-wrapper" id="clearway" runat="server" visible="false">
       <a target="_blank" href="https://testclearway.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-desktop custom-icon">
             <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
          </i>
          <span class="hidden-xs">Connect via Clearway</span>
       </a>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in the code-behind, just say:

```
pnlClear.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

`visible` is not a valid HTML attribute.

If you are using **HTML5**, you can try `hidden`. One thing to note is `hidden` doesn't take `true` or `false`. You will need to remove `hidden` attribute if you want to show the element again, just assigning `false` to `hidden` won't show it.

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper" id="clearway" runat="server" hidden>
   <a target="_blank" href="https://testclearway.com/">
      <i class="fa fa-desktop custom-icon">
         <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
      </i>
      <span class="hidden-xs">Connect via Clearway</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

---

Also, you can use CSS `display: none;` to hide it. If you want to reserve the space the element is taking, use `visibility: hidden;` instead. You can check the details about the comparison [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

Comment: You're seem to be right. There are just so many languages and frameworks and platforms I deal with that it all just mushes together every now and then! However, trying to set that attribute programmatically results in three problems: 1) cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("hidden", Nothing) always produces hidden="", 2) the DIV never does hide like this, and 3) attempting to manually set the DIV 's hidden attribute in FireFox Developer Edition still turns up as hidden="" and won't hide the DIV either.

Comment: No problem, this syntax mush thing happens to all developers. I tried `hidden=""` in a code snippet, and it works for me in both Chrome and Firefox. I'm not a .net developer, so I did some quick research on [`SetAttributeValue `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue(v=vs.110).aspx) function. I think you can do `cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("hidden", "")` to set the attribute, and use `cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("hidden", null)` to remove the attribute. Hope this helps. @ShieldOfSalvation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `runat="server"` is a hint that ASP.NET uses to id Server Side controls, and call the render methods.

You cannot set the runat server at runtime.

If you want to hide that element you have to whether add `runat=server`at design time in `clearway` or hide the element client side. Adding a CSS class or a style (display:none, visibility:hidden)

Answer (score 0):

`Visible` with upper case "V" is an attribute for asp.net controls not html controls, And `runat="server` does not change the html control to asp.net control even if you have added this befor runtime. Instead to hide your element you can set it's display style to **none**. Or you can add this css style to the page:

```
.hiddenDiv{
    display: none;
}
```

And do this:

```
cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("class", "hiddenDiv")
```

Comment: I tried your way like this and got some wacky results:             cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("style", ".hiddenDiv{ display: none; }")
            cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("class", "hiddenDiv") ....which yielded this markup: <div class="hiddenDiv" id="clearpath" style=".hiddenDiv{ display: none; }">   ...but I'm getting wacky effects on the page, so this is a no go.

Comment: I did not say that... If you want to directly add the style you must do this: `cmsClearwayNode.SetAttributeValue("style", "display: none; ") ;` This is enough. But If you want to use the second way, The css style `.hiddenDiv{ display: none; }` must add in a `style` tag in your page, not in attribute of your control.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only good workaround I've found while trying to wrap up this code is setting cmsClearwayNode.InnerHtml = "". The node content drops off and everything else falls into place nicely. It's an OK solution, but I just thought setting attributes or styles would be more elegant.